# `Syscall param epoll_ctl(event) points to uninitialised` in simple boost server on arm64

Tags: c++11, boost, arm

I am running this simple c++ server on jetson nano ARM platform:

```
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    tcp::acceptor a(svc);
    a.open(tcp::v4());
    a.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    a.bind({{}, 6767}); // bind to port 6767 on localhost
    a.listen(5);
    using session = std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>;
    std::function<void()>        do_accept;
    std::function<void(session)> do_session;
    do_session = [&](session s) {
        // do a read
        auto buf = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(1024);
        s->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(*buf), [&,s,buf](error_code ec, size_t bytes) {
            if (ec)
                std::cerr << "read failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            else {
                std::cout << "Echo to " << s->remote_endpoint(ec) << ": " << std::string(buf->data(), bytes);
                if (ec)
                    std::cerr << "endpoint failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                else
                    async_write(*s, boost::asio::buffer(*buf), [&,s,buf](error_code ec, size_t) {
                        if (ec) std::cerr << "write failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
                    });
                do_session(s); // full duplex, can read while writing, using a second buffer
            }
        });
    };
    do_accept = [&] {
        auto s = std::make_shared<session::element_type>(svc);
        a.async_accept(*s, [&,s](error_code ec) {
            if (ec)
                std::cerr << "accept failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
            else {
                do_session(s);
                do_accept(); // accept the next
            }
        });
    };
    do_accept(); // kick-off
    svc.run();   // wait for shutdown (Ctrl-C or failure)
```

If I launch it with valgrind, then I get following messages:

```
stiv@nano:~/jsoft/tests$ valgrind ./build/ImageServerTest 
==1120== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1120== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1120== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1120== Command: ./build/ImageServerTest
==1120== 
==1120== Syscall param epoll_ctl(event) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==1120==    at 0x4B57CD8: epoll_ctl (syscall-template.S:78)
==1120==    by 0x131AAF: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::epoll_reactor(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13B7F3: boost::asio::io_service::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x130F5B: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::io_service::service::key const&, boost::asio::io_service::service* (*)(boost::asio::io_service&)) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13A937: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>() (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x137C1B: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13582B: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::reactive_socket_service_base(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13D53F: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::reactive_socket_service(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13CD3F: boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::socket_acceptor_service(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13C77F: boost::asio::io_service::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x130F5B: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::io_service::service::key const&, boost::asio::io_service::service* (*)(boost::asio::io_service&)) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13C2F7: boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >() (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==  Address 0x1ffefffc5c is on thread 1's stack
==1120==  in frame #1, created by boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::epoll_reactor(boost::asio::io_service&) (???:)
==1120== 
==1120== Syscall param epoll_ctl(event) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==1120==    at 0x4B57CD8: epoll_ctl (syscall-template.S:78)
==1120==    by 0x131B07: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::epoll_reactor(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13B7F3: boost::asio::io_service::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x130F5B: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::io_service::service::key const&, boost::asio::io_service::service* (*)(boost::asio::io_service&)) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13A937: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>() (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x137C1B: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor& boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor>(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13582B: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::reactive_socket_service_base(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13D53F: boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::reactive_socket_service(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13CD3F: boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::socket_acceptor_service(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13C77F: boost::asio::io_service::service* boost::asio::detail::service_registry::create<boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >(boost::asio::io_service&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x130F5B: boost::asio::detail::service_registry::do_use_service(boost::asio::io_service::service::key const&, boost::asio::io_service::service* (*)(boost::asio::io_service&)) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x13C2F7: boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>& boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >() (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==  Address 0x1ffefffc5c is on thread 1's stack
==1120==  in frame #1, created by boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::epoll_reactor(boost::asio::io_service&) (???:)
==1120== 
^C==1120== 
==1120== Process terminating with default action of signal 2 (SIGINT)
==1120==    at 0x4B575B0: epoll_pwait (epoll_pwait.c:42)
==1120==    by 0x132803: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(bool, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x133D23: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x1337FF: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x134073: boost::asio::io_service::run() (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120==    by 0x12C1D7: main (in /home/stiv/jsoft/tests/build/ImageServerTest)
==1120== 
==1120== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1120==     in use at exit: 945 bytes in 9 blocks
==1120==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 1 frees, 73,649 bytes allocated
==1120== 
==1120== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1120==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1120==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1120==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1120==    still reachable: 945 bytes in 9 blocks
==1120==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1120== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1120== 
==1120== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1120== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==1120== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What does it mean? Is it a bug in boost asio, or in valgrind? How do I fix it?

**Some background information:** I had to dig into this because I have crashes on production application, which are hard to reproduce. Crashes themselves don't reproduce under valgrind, but valgrind indicates exactly same error for production code. According to logs, most probably in production it crashes on exactly same line starting web server (not 100% sure of course). So I decided to isolate this web piece and I see that valgrind problem is still here, though I don't see crash itself.

**UPDATE:** tried upgrading from boost 65 to lastest 75, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your process and printing out the variables just before making a syscall? What arguments does asio pass there? Have you tried downgrading to earlier boost, could this help (just to confirm the problem)? However, I believe, the valgrind on arm64 is [buggy](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1215) and maybe you should look for the crash reasons somewhere else. How sure you are the crash happens exactly because of this? And if you aren't, why simply not to add debug logging statements and see the place it crashes finally? You should be able to get the procdump also.

Comment: Stepan, could you please share complete example sources (ImageServerTest) to allow us to run the example? What is the exact version of Linux distribution (l4t) used?

Comment: @osgx, just simply wrap my code in main(). I am using Debian ubuntu on jetson nano: https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-nano-developer-kit

Comment: I don't believe the uninitialized bytes warning is at all related to your crash.  The struct is 64 bits wide, but only 32 are initialized or used (a file descriptor) (note it is never paired with a 'branch depends on uninitialized value' error!   Bad on the library for not bzero'ing or otherwise initializing, but your later exit on SIGINT likely isn't caused by that.  Google for the warning and you'll see lots of people getting tripped up by it!

Comment: You'll need to run in a debugger and catch the SIGINT signal to understand where it's being generated - the process exit is the correct default behavior.   (We're assuming you're not ^C'ing your app and not telling us :p)

Comment: Under debugger its not possible to reproduce the problem.